# Custom tool warnings when using VS2010 service reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xsd, wsdl, service-reference, firstdata

I am trying to get going on using First Data's Global Gateway Web Service API. The first strange thing is that I need to download the wsdl and xsd files to my local machine. Then use the local machine's copy for the service reference. I haven't used many web services, so I figured that was okay.

After adding them and try to compile it I get the following errors:

```
Warning 1   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: There was a problem loading the XSD documents provided: a reference to a schema element with name 'AVSResponse' and namespace 'http://secure.linkpt.net/fdggwsapi/schemas_us/fdggwsapi' could not be resolved because the element definition could not be found in the schema for targetNamespace 'http://secure.linkpt.net/fdggwsapi/schemas_us/fdggwsapi'. Please check the XSD documents provided and try again.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://secure.linkpt.net/fdggwsapi/schemas_us/fdggwsapi']/wsdl:portType[@name='FDGGWSApiOrder'] C:\Documents and Settings\user\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\sltnProcessCreditCard\ProcessCreditCard\Service References\ServiceReference\Reference.svcmap    1   1   ProcessCreditCard

Warning 2   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://secure.linkpt.net/fdggwsapi/schemas_us/fdggwsapi']/wsdl:portType[@name='FDGGWSApiOrder']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://secure.linkpt.net/fdggwsapi/schemas_us/fdggwsapi']/wsdl:binding[@name='FDGGWSApiOrderBinding']   C:\Documents and Settings\user\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\sltnProcessCreditCard\ProcessCreditCard\Service References\ServiceReference\Reference.svcmap    1   1   ProcessCreditCard

Warning 3   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://secure.linkpt.net/fdggwsapi/schemas_us/fdggwsapi']/wsdl:binding[@name='FDGGWSApiOrderBinding']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://secure.linkpt.net/fdggwsapi/schemas_us/fdggwsapi']/wsdl:service[@name='FDGGWSApiOrderService']/wsdl:port[@name='FDGGWSApiOrderPort'] C:\Documents and Settings\user\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\sltnProcessCreditCard\ProcessCreditCard\Service References\ServiceReference\Reference.svcmap    1   1   ProcessCreditCard
```

I tried the "[Reuse types in referenced assemblies](http://www.marcusoft.net/2009/01/custom-tool-warning-cannot-import.html)" mentioned in many places and that doesn't fix it. Has anyone come across this error? How did you fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757990/why-does-this-wsdl-file-generate-an-empty-service-proxy-in-vs2008/758011#758011) that seems to at least let me continue working. In the mean time, I am open for other ideas.

Update: Quoting the answer for ease of finding it:

> Try adding it as .NET 2.0 Web Reference.
>
> Go to Add Service Reference, then click the "Advanced" button. Then you're given to option to add it as a .NET 2.0 Web Reference. I did this, and got it to work. I couldn't via the standard "Add Service Reference"